# stream S3 bucket via websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket

I need to stream s3 bucket files to a web browser via websockets.(kind of tail -f)
Each file contains json lines, which I need to filter by user's demand (kind of grep)

the constraint of the design is, that I cant use other non free services than AWS services.

any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to achieve this natively in S3.

What can be done instead is;

1. If you are proxying the upload to S3 via your backend server then you may implement websockets on the server so that it will communicate with the browser by emitting a "FileCreated" event every time an upload is successful.
2. If you are uploading the file direct to S3 from the browser then you can implement a lambda function that will be triggered for each successful file upload. This lambda function will then notify your backend server via an http request and it will then relay the event to the browser by emitting websockets events.

Both options won't required additional services.